# Upgrade every enabled repository using unattended-upgrades

Tags: debian, upgrade, unattended-upgrades

Is there a way to configure unattended-upgrades to upgrade all enabled repositories (including third parties)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: as mentioned in `/usr/share/doc/unattended-upgrades/README.md.gz`, edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` so that its `Origins-Pattern` section reads

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
    "origin=*";
};
```

This will apply all available upgrades, as determined by `apt` pinning, from all configured repositories.

Comment: Thank you! I should grow some patience and better read the docs...